# Proper use of meta tag for keywords

Tags: html, google-search, google-search-console

I'm making a website and I need it to pop up on google search. It´s for a niche topic so it shouldn't be hard to find.

I've been using the meta tag to add keywords and my page has been indexed by google. Search console also tells me that some people have clicked on it.

I´m using it like this:

```
 <meta name="keywords" content="keyword1, keyword2, keyword3, keyword4, ...">
```

I'm sure this is a common issue but I can´t find a way to fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proper use is you don't use this tag at all.
This tag is not used like 20 years already.
Google doesn't take it in consider nor do any other search engine.
Therefore you can write anything to it, Google and any other search engine will ignore it.

Comment: What should I use then?

Comment: Title, desctiption, website's content, JSON-LD (rich content), links (internal and external) to this page

Comment: So there's no way to "cheat" and have  bunch of keywords to help me pop up in google searches? Thanks for the help :)

Comment: If there was a way to cheat then everybody would cheat... So yea, there is not.